# File date returning wrong in Delphi xe5

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

I am using a simple command to get the file date from a file, but keep getting the wrong date.

On my computer i looked and saw the date was 14/3/2014.
But when i run the command i get 30/12/1999 no matter what file i try, it stays the same return date.

I've tried

```
BackupFileDate:=FileAge(S);;
    originalfiledate:=FileAge(fileName);
```

And

```
BackupFileDate:=GetFileModDate(S);
originalfiledate:=GetFileModDate(Filename);

function GetFileModDate(filename : string) : TDateTime;
var
   F : TSearchRec;
begin
   FindFirst(filename,faAnyFile,F);
   Result := F.TimeStamp;

   //Result := F.Time;
   FindClose(F);
end;
```

Both have the same result.
PS: both BackupFileDate and originalfiledate are now defined as TDate, I've already tried TDateTime as-well with the same result.

I would like to get the date and time last edited of the file.

Comment: Check the return value of FindFirst. F might be left filled with junk if FindFirst fails.

Comment: @user You cannot accept comments. And you can comment yourself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[FileAge](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.SysUtils.FileAge) returns a time stamp used by the OS to record information such as the date and time a file was modified.

You should use the [FileDateToDateTime](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.SysUtils.FileDateToDateTime) function to convert the Integer value to a more manageable TDateTime format:

```
FileDateToDateTime(FileAge(fileName));
```

Note:

```
function FileAge(const FileName: string): Integer; overload;
```

is deprecated. There is another version of FileAge

```
function FileAge(const FileName: string; out FileDateTime: TDateTime; FollowLink: Boolean = True): Boolean;
```

that returns the time stamp of FileName in the FileDateTime output parameter.

```
FileAge(filename, timeDate);
```

EDIT

Depending on the use of the data, it may be (very) important to [convert from UTC to local time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15567194/how-to-convert-local-time-to-utc-time-in-delphi-xe2-and-how-to-convert-it-back).

Comment: You've not covered the second excerpt, which works fine. Or time zones. Better hope that asker is not in GMT!

Comment: Of course you're right, time zones must be considered!

Answer (score 4):

**tl;dr** Use [`TFile.GetLastWriteTime`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.IOUtils.TDirectory.GetLastWriteTime) or [`TFile.GetLastWriteTimeUtc`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.IOUtils.TDirectory.GetLastWriteTimeUtc).

---

Your first attempt fails because `FileAge` returns DOS date time value. That's completely different from a `TDateTime`.

Your second piece of code essentially works, modulo the fact that you neglected to check for errors. The likely explanation for the error is that you passed an invalid file name. When the call to `FindFirst` fails, the search record that is returned is undefined.

The `TimeStamp` property of `TSearchRec` converts the file time from UTC to local, and then converts from file time to `TDateTime`.

You'd want to fix the lack of error handling like this:

```
function GetFileModDate(const FileName: string): TDateTime;
var
  F: TSearchRec;
begin
  if FindFirst(filename, faAnyFile, F)<>0 then
    raise SomeException.Create('...');
  Result := F.TimeStamp;
  FindClose(F);
end;
```

You should be clear that this returns a `TDateTime` in local time.

That said, I would do it in a platform independent way using `IOUtils`. Specifically [`TFile.GetLastWriteTime`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.IOUtils.TDirectory.GetLastWriteTime) or [`TFile.GetLastWriteTimeUtc`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.IOUtils.TDirectory.GetLastWriteTimeUtc) depending on how you want to deal with time zones.