# DateTimeToUnix Delphi 5?

Tags: delphi, datetime, delphi-5

I am trying to use the ***DateTimeToUnix*** function in ***Delphi 5***. DateTimeToUnix uses DateUtils (Which wasn't introduced until Delphi 6 according to some information found on the web); following this logic I ascertain that Delphi 5 does not support this function.

A question similar to this was asked on stackoverflow and marked as a duplicate, however; there was nothing mentioned about Delphi 5 in the answers.

Original Question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27885090/delphi-5-how-to-get-current-time-now-in-unix-timestamp?lq=1

I believe The code found at the following website answers mine and the original question: http://www.swissdelphicenter.com/torry/showcode.php?id=844

```
unit Unix_Utils;

interface

Uses SysUtils;

function DateTimeToUnix(ConvDate: TDateTime): Longint;
function UnixToDateTime(USec: Longint): TDateTime;

implementation

const UnixStartDate: TDateTime = 25569.0; // Sets UnixStartDate to TDateTime of 01/01/1970

    function DateTimeToUnix(ConvDate: TDateTime): Longint;
    begin
        //example: DateTimeToUnix(now);
        Result := Round((ConvDate - UnixStartDate) * 86400);
    end;

    function UnixToDateTime(USec: Longint): TDateTime;
    begin
        //Example: UnixToDateTime(1003187418);
        Result := (Usec / 86400) + UnixStartDate;
    end;

end.
```

Thomas Greiner is the author of the original code. "The above code has been modified from its original version. It has been formatted to fit the screen"

**Steps to use the above code in Delphi 5:**

1. File > New... > New Tab > Unit > OK
2. Replace the entire contents of the new unit with the code shown above
3. Save the new unit "unix_utils" somewhere like C:\Program Files\Borland\Delphi5\Lib\
4. If DateTimeToUnix is ever needed: Project > Add to Project... > browse to unix_utils > Then click open
5. I believe if unix_utils file is saved in the aforementioned location it can just be added to the "*Uses*" section of a unit???

So is this a duplicate?

Comment: You have to either add the .pas file to every project that needs it, or else compile the .pas file into a .dcu and place that in a folder on your IDE's library path.  Either way, you can then use the unit in your `uses` clause.

Comment: Thanks Remy... ".dcu" will do.

Comment: Don't save it under Delphi5\Lib. Just add the unit to any project that needs it. Or, put it in a shared location and add that location to your search path. But whatever you do, don't modify Delphi's lib folder.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking about. Task is pretty trivial - compute number of seconds since 1 Jan 1970 given number of days since 31 Dec 1899. But you have to remember what TDateTime is local, with Epoch Time is UTC.

Comment: Yes I would consider this a duplicate. And instead of providing an answer inside the question, I suggest you go to the older question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23968919/224704) and add your Delphi 5 answer there.