# function DateTimeToUnix how to use it?

Tags: delphi

could you guys give a an example of a code that prints DateTimeToUnix in Pascal?

Found out a topic talking about in Delphi ([DateTimeToUnix in UTC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23968919/datetimetounix-in-utc)), but i cant find a code example anywhere.

```
function DateTimeToUnix(

  const AValue: TDateTime

):Int64;
```

Here is an example in c#

```
    public static int UnixTimeStamp()
    {
        return (int)DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalSeconds;
    }
}
```

Also, i did a little search and this function seems to print the System time without using timezone (UTC), so how i could adjust the result to the timezone i want (eg. UTC -3).

Thanks,

Comment: If there is an algorithm (wikipedia or the places where you found the other language samples), then there should be a way to code it also in Pascal. Maybe you start with it and when - possibly with the help of others - it is finished, then there is some code sample :-)

Comment: What do you mean with "how to print DateTimeToUnix"? Just call the function DateTimeToUnix. The function converts a TDateTime value to Unix epoch time already. The function returns an Int64 which you can convert to String.