# What am I doing wrong converting these times from UTC to Local?

Tags: datetime, delphi, github-api, utc

Using the GitHub API, timestamps are returned in UTC. I'm using the following to convert these into a Delphi `TDateTime`...

```
  with TXSDateTime.Create do
    try
      XSToNative('2019-07-27T19:33:02Z');
      Result:= AsDateTime;
    finally
      Free;
    end;
```

I don't recall where I found that function.

The value `2019-07-27T19:33:02Z` comes directly from the GitHub API on a particular repository's "pushed_at" field (last pushed). After converting it using the function above, I get (formatted to string):

`2019-07-27 11:33:02`

Now I take this value and I try to convert it to local time. My local time is EST, and I know for a fact that particular repository I last pushed it yesterday at 3:33 PM. I confirmed that directly on GitHub's website.

I have used both methods as found in [the top two answers on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15567194/how-to-convert-local-time-to-utc-time-in-delphi-xe2-and-how-to-convert-it-back). Specifically the functions `LocalDateTimeFromUTCDateTime` and `UnivDateTime2LocalDateTime` However, the results are both backwards. Rather than adding 4 hours, both methods are instead subtracting 4 hours.

So the result I get from both is

`2019-07-27 07:33:02`

I know for a fact I didn't do that push at 7:33 AM. I wasn't even awake yet.

In fact, if I use the *wrong* function `DateTime2UnivDateTime()` then I actually get the correct result.

What am I doing wrong here, and how do I get the correct result for local time?

I barely understand the science behind time zones.

---

**EDIT**

It looks like that first function is resulting in double the time shift, so I didn't realize it was already attempting to convert to local time. But rather than subtracting 4 hours, it subtracted 8 hours. So I was thrown off and thinking I still needed to convert it to local time. But why is it shifting twice?

Comment: There's an ISO8601ToDate method in System.DateUtils

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) convert ISO time to Delphi TDateTime:

```
function ISOToDateTime(const AISODateTime: string): TDateTime;
var
  I: Integer;
  VDate, VTime: TDateTime;
  VFormatSettings: TFormatSettings;
begin
  // ISO format: 2009-07-06T01:53:23Z

  VFormatSettings.DateSeparator := '-';
  VFormatSettings.ShortDateFormat := 'yyyy-mm-dd';
  VFormatSettings.TimeSeparator := ':';
  VFormatSettings.ShortTimeFormat := 'hh:nn:ss';

  I := Pos('T', AISODateTime); 
  VDate := StrToDate(Copy(AISODateTime, 1, I - 1), VFormatSettings);
  VTime := StrToTime(Copy(AISODateTime, I + 1, 8), VFormatSettings);

  Result := Trunc(VDate) + Frac(VTime);
end;
```

2) convert UTC time to Local time:

```
function UniversalToLocalTime(const AUtcTime: TDateTime): TDateTime;

  function _GetSystemTzOffset: Extended;
  var
    VTmpDate: TDateTime;
    ST1, ST2: TSystemTime;
    TZ: TTimeZoneInformation;
  begin
    GetTimeZoneInformation(TZ);
    DateTimeToSystemTime(AUtcTime, ST1);
    SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTime(@TZ, ST1, ST2);
    VTmpDate := SystemTimeToDateTime(ST2);
    Result := MinutesBetween(VTmpDate, AUtcTime) / 60;
    if VTmpDate < AUtcTime then begin
      Result := -Result;
    end;
  end;

var
  VOffset: Extended;
begin
  VOffset := _GetSystemTzOffset;
  if VOffset = 0 then begin
    Result := AUtcTime;
  end else begin
    Result := IncHour(AUtcTime, Trunc(VOffset));
    Result := IncMinute(Result, Round(Frac(VOffset) * 60));
  end;
end;
```

Comment: That first part did it. The method I was using is apparently flawed.